# Button with postbackurl specified doesn't actually go to the target

Tags: asp.net, button, postbackurl

I have a folder in my website called order in which 2 pages "Partner.aspx" and "ViewBasket.aspx" are present. In my first page i.e Partner.aspx, I have a button with the code :

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnViewBasket" PostBackUrl="~/ViewBasket.aspx"
 SkinID="MSWButtonM" Text="VIEW CART" meta:resourcekey="btnViewBasketResource1"/>
```

But on click of this button it doesnt go to the Viewbasket.aspx page.
Can somebody please help?

Comment: share both URLs here.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnViewBasket" PostBackUrl="/order/ViewBasket.aspx" 
SkinID="MSWButtonM" Text="VIEW CART" meta:resourcekey="btnViewBasketResource1"/>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. Yeah there was this mistake with the URL.And also,I found out that there was issue with a piece of code in another file. The button was running page validations and hence was not posting back to the given URL